# Webpack bundling unused imports (no tree shaking)

Tags: javascript, webpack

##### Issue

I can't get Webpack to exclude an unused **import**, even with `sideEffects: false` in `package.json`.

##### Example

```js
// Entry.js
import {controller} from './Setting.js'
```

```js
// Setting.js
import Component from './Component.js' // Not used by Entry.js

export const controller = {};
export const view = Component(controller); // Not used by Entry.js
```

```js
// Component.js 
import 'huge/side-effect/library' - Not used by Entry.js, still gets bundled

export default Component() {}
```

In this scenario, `Entry.js` only imports `controller` which is pure and should need not other dependencies. But, even after optimizing my settings as much as possible for tree shaking, `'huge/side-effect/library'` still gets bundled.

##### Configuration

```js
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { modules: false }]],
};
```

```json
// package.json
{
  "sideEffects": false
}
```

^ For testing purposes only. The library still gets bundled.

```js
//webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  /* ... */
  optimization: {
    usedExports: true, // Also tried --mode production
  },
}
```

##### Workaround

Simply defining `controller` in a file that doesn't import `Component`.

But I'm curious if there's a way to exclude it if it's in the same file.

##### Note

If I don't use `Component` in `Setting.js`, its source and the library don't get bundled. So Webpack sees that since it's being used in the imported file, then that usage itself could have a side effect.

So, I've tried using `/*@__PURE__*/` & `/*#__PURE__*/` (converting the code to function calls), but the library still gets bundled unfortunately.

Comment: I have almost the same problem. Have you found any solution for this ?

Comment: I switched to Vite which uses Rollup to bundle. Rollup bundles according to AST so it's able to figure out the actual functions/variables being used and include them. You could just go with rollup directly too.